# How to prevent terminal from killing process with ctrl+z

Tags: command-line, bash, vim

I know that you can restore the process by hitting `fg` and enter after you stop a job with `ctrl+z`, but I don't think I've ever intended to stop a job.. ever. e.g. I always bump it when typing `ctrl+x` in VIM.

How can I prevent my bash terminal from stopping jobs when I hit `ctrl+z`?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? (although it may not matter)

Comment: ah found my dupe. sorry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879219/vim-how-to-temporarily-exit-vim-and-go-back

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using 'unset suspend' in **~/.vimrc** or **/etc/vimrc**, or running **vim** with '-Z' (to disable suspend).